# Add Variables from class to another similar class

Tags: php

I have two similar classes, which contains a lot of integer variables.

I need a way to add all the variables from one class to another class.

my class is similar to this

```
class statistics{

var $Variable_1
var $Variable_2
var $Variable_3
var $Variable_4
var $Variable_5
var $Variable_6
var $Variable_7
var $Variable_8
var $Variable_9
var $Variable_10

/* 
.. to 100 
*/

}
```

All I need is to `ADD` all these variables from the `first` class to the `second` class, and I think that my code is too long for `php`.

```
$class1->Variable_1 += $class2->Variable_1


    /* 
    .. to 100 
    */
```

There is no chance to use `for loop` or `foraech` because the variables doesn't has anykeys. Moreover, the variables names are not contain any numbers.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why don't you just create a function within the class that you want to pass the variables to.  You can pass a whole class and handle it as required within the function?

Comment: Inheritance, public attributes, getter methods, ... It's up to you to choose.

Comment: Also, why store them as individual variables, why not store the data in an array?

Comment: Like Coulton said - why not an array? As soon as you have variables differing in number in name, that's a hint that you **must** use an array, which is why arrays were invented in the first place.

Comment: I can't change the class right now, my script is already use it like this. If there are no solutions I will think about re creating the class as an `array` of data.

Comment: so use foreach or get_object_vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
class statistics{

    var $Variable_1;
    var $Variable_2;
    var $Variable_3;
    var $Variable_4;
    var $Variable_5;
    var $Variable_6;
    var $Variable_7;
    var $Variable_8;
    var $Variable_9;
    var $Variable_10;

}

$class1 = new statistics();
$class2 = new statistics();

$class1->Variable_1 = 5;
$class2->Variable_1 = 2;

$object_vars = get_object_vars($class1);
foreach ($object_vars as $name => $value) {
    $class2->$name += $value;
}

echo($class2->Variable_1); //result in 7.
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it would be better not to use the `var` keyword. Today there are three levels of visibility (`public protected private`) use them.

Then, as given above, inheritance is what you want as when a class B extends A it IS a A but with more attributes or operation or sense. So in your B class there will be your variables.

Other thing I found :

> There is no chance to use for loop or foraech because the variables doesn't has anykeys.

It is quite false. The default behaviour of foreach over object is to traverse all public attributes (defined with `public`or `var`), given their name as key and their value as value, so :

```
foreach(new class1() as $key=>$value){
     echo $key.'=>'.$value;
}
```

will print all couple attribute name => attribute value.

If you want to add dynamicaly variables to a php object, I think it is possible by using simply `$yourObject->yourAttribute = 42;` 
If you can't, I'm quite sure you can use __set and __get magic methods to create this behaviour :

```
class class2{
    public function __set($name,$value){
       $this->$name = $value;//will create a public attribute with $name as name
    }
}
```